# What is wrong with this vanilla JavaScript colors filter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I have a lot of different rainbow color `div` with list of 8 items. 7 sections with the name of the colors and an 'all' option. The code filters the colors.

The problem happens when moving from the 'all' section to other sections or the opposite, the container moves to the right, but there is no problem when moving between color sections

```js
let myList   = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
let myColors = document.querySelectorAll('.colors div');

myList.forEach(item => {
  item.onclick = function() {
    myColors.forEach(color => {
      color.style.display = 'none'
    })
    let theTarget = this.dataset.target;
    myColors.forEach(color => {
      if (theTarget === color.dataset.color || theTarget === 'all') {
        color.style.display = 'block'
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li data-target="all">All</li>
    <li data-target="red">Red</li>
    <li data-target="orange">Orange</li>
    <li data-target="yellow">Yellow</li>
    <li data-target="green">Green</li>
    <li data-target="blue">Blue</li>
    <li data-target="indigo">Indigo</li>
    <li data-target="violet">Violet</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="colors">
    <div style="background: #f00" data-color="red">red</div>
    <div style="background: #4b0082" data-color="indigo">indigo</div>
    <div style="background: #00800d" data-color="green">green</div>
    <div style="background: #ffa500" data-color="orange">orange</div>
    <div style="background: #ee82ee" data-color="violet">violet</div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited your snippet as the `div` elements within `.colors` had no content, and so were not displayed. Also note that the snippet does not show the behaviour you describe. Most likely it's an issue caused by some CSS elsewhere in your page. Please edit to include all the code to recreate the problem

Answer (score 0):

you have unnecessarily complicated things

```js
const allColors   = document.querySelectorAll('.colors div')

document.querySelector('div.container').onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('li') ) return

  let choosed = target.dataset.target
    , isAll   = choosed === 'all'
    ;
  allColors.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('noDisplay', !(isAll || el.dataset.color===choosed)) )
  }
```

```css
div.container li {
  cursor : pointer;
  }
.noDisplay {
  display : none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li data-target="all"    > All    </li>
    <li data-target="red"    > Red   </li>
    <li data-target="orange" > Orange </li>
    <li data-target="yellow" > Yellow </li>
    <li data-target="green"  > Green  </li>
    <li data-target="blue"   > Blue   </li>
    <li data-target="indigo" > Indigo </li>
    <li data-target="violet" > Violet </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="colors">
    <div style="background: #f00"    data-color="red"   >&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="background: #4b0082" data-color="indigo">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="background: #00800d" data-color="green" >&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="background: #ffa500" data-color="orange">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="background: #ee82ee" data-color="violet">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="background: #f00"    data-color="red"   >&nbsp;</div>
<!--    ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```